# Why is $x^{10} -1=(x-1)(x-w)(x-w^2)...(x-w^9)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

I understand that since polynomial $x^{10} -1$ is polynomial of 10th degree,we have $10 x$-es.
However I don't understand why we can have universal w that will be root raised to any degree lower than n(level of polynomial).
Is it related to the number 1 in polynomial.
I have an ambition to raise my knowledge of polynomials from high school math to grasp little bit more complex concepts especially primitive roots of unity, cyclotomic polynomials.
So far I can't completely grasp it,this is one of the parts that I am currently stuck.

Comment: What do you mean, "We Jace 10 $x$-es?" Presumably you mean $10$ roots?